# How can you send calendar invites on iPhone 5 without using iCloud?

Tags: iphone, ios, ical

How can you send out calendar invites in the iPhone 5 Calendar app? I have synced my phone calendar with one Gmail account and Outlook.

How can I create an entry on my phone and invite attendees without using iCloud?

Answer (score 2):

If you invite someone from the Gmail calendar, it should send invites to persons via Google's Service.